# Replace method in java

Tags: java

can you help me with this code:

```
 s=br.readLine(); 
 s.replace("ch", "c");  
 s.replace("ch", "c");
 s.replace("sh", "s");
 s.replace("zh", "z"); 
 s.replace("Ch", "C");


s.replace("Sh", "S");
s.replace("Zh", "Z"); 
System.out.println(s);
```

The problem is that  the replace method doesn't work, It doesn't replace the ch,sh,zh chars in the String s, so on the output i still get the same string without change.

Comment: String are immutables in java

Comment: you need to add assignment for each replace for example s = s.replace("ch", "c");

Answer (score 5, accepted):

String is immutable. `replace` returns a new `String`, which must be assigned back to `s` in order for `s` to refer (in the end) to the output `String` after all the replacements :

```
 s=br.readLine(); 
 s=s.replace("ch", "c");  
 s=s.replace("ch", "c");
 s=s.replace("sh", "s");
 s=s.replace("zh", "z"); 
 s=s.replace("Ch", "C");
 s=s.replace("Sh", "S");
 s=s.replace("Zh", "Z"); 
 System.out.println(s);
```